# Xamarin.Forms leak on Android doing simple push/pop of page?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, xamarin.forms

I'm investigating a memory leak (or leaks) which seem to be core to our Forms app.

We're using FreshMvvm, which previously had a pretty bad leak due to Pages/PageModels not being garbage collected. Michael Ridland (FreshMvvm) author) fixed that, which is great.

However, we're still seeing the figure returned by GC.GetTotalMemory() steadily increase. It *does* decrease, but the general trend is upwards.

I've stripped things right back so that I've just got a plain Page which pushes another page and we can then pop back to the first.

Doing this, I'm seeing GC.GetTotalMemory() generally increase by 2K - 4K every cycle. This is after forcibly calling GC.Collect();

We're running Xamarin.Forms 2.3.4.270 - I know this is quite old, but we really don't want to upgrade as we don't want to introduce 'new Forms' bugs! However, I have tried experimentally upgrading to 2.5.0.121934, and I see the same behaviour (as well as aspects of the app stop working with this version).

Short of using Profiler, are there any investigative techniques I can use to find the culprit?

My next step will be to strip more and more out!

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar issue in the past with Xamarin.Forms memory leaks and to help figure what views/pages were the culprit this class was created:

```
public static class Refs
{
    private static readonly List<WeakReference> _refs = new List<WeakReference>();

    public static readonly BindableProperty IsWatchedProperty = BindableProperty.CreateAttached("IsWatched", typeof(bool), typeof(Refs), false, propertyChanged: OnIsWatchedChanged);

    public static bool GetIsWatched(BindableObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsWatchedProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsWatched(BindableObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsWatchedProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnIsWatchedChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        AddRef(bindable);
    }

    public async static void AddRef(object p)
    {
        GC.Collect();
        await Task.Delay(100);
        GC.Collect();

        _refs.Add(new WeakReference(p));
        foreach (var @ref in _refs)
        {
            if (@ref.IsAlive)
            {
                var obj = @ref.Target;
                Debug.WriteLine("IsAlive: " + obj.GetType().Name);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("IsAlive: False");
            }
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("---------------");
    }
}
```

Then to use it you can use the IsWatched property in your pages xaml or in code behind you can just do `Refs.AddRef(this);` after `InitializeComponent();` and just navigate to and from the page several times. If it is being gc'ed the console should print IsAlive: False if not it will print out the type.

Most often the leaks we had were fixed by clearing the BindingContext and/or setting some things to null when leaving the page.

```
protected override void OnParentSet()
{
    base.OnParentSet();

    if (Parent == null)
    {
        BindingContext = null;
    }
}
```